# JPA 2.1 application requiring managed server reboot upon redeployment to WebLogic 12.2.1

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic12c

When using JPA 2.1 in our current application, we encounter a 500 internal server error when sending web service request. The issue resolves and JPA works properly only after a reboot of the application's managed server. I'm using eclipselink as my JPA provider since this is what is provided on the server. My current deployment unzips the ear file and deployed an exploded file that contains META-INF (application.xml, MANIFEST.MF, weblogic-application.xml) and the war file which contains the classes and persistence.xml file. I'm currently deploying using the wldeploy ant script with redeploy as the action.

JPA only works after the initial deployment or a bounce of the managed server if I was to redeploy.

Could this be an issue with my deployment or the structure or the EAR and WAR files or could it be an implementation issue with JPA?

I've included the @RequestScoped annotation on the web service class.

I've included the beans.xml file in my web folder with the following line:

```
bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
```

My web folder contains the following:

```
web/WEB-INF/classes/persistence.xml
web/beans.xml
web/web.xml
web/weblogic.xml
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="DB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/PublicAPI</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Beans.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
 </beans>
```

weblogic.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web- 
 app"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
 http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<context-root>/PublicAPI/</context-root>
```

WebService

```
@ApplicationPath("")
@Path("inventory/")
@Api(value = "Engineering Public API")
@RequestScoped
public class SsmcResource {
    @Inject
    private SsmcListProcedure ssmcListProcedure;

    @POST
    @Path("GetSSMCList")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SsmcResponse getSSMCList(SsmcRequest ssmcRequest)
    {
        SsmcResponse response = null;
        response = new SsmcResponse();
        SsmcList ssmc = ssmcRequest.getSsmc();
        CallerStatus callerStatus = ssmcRequest.getCallerStatus();
        InitializeCallerStatus(callerStatus);
        response.setSsmc(ssmcListProcedure.getSSMCList(ssmc.getSeries(), ssmc.getStyle(), ssmc.getMaterial(), ssmc.getColor()));
        return response;
    }
}
```

JPA Class:

```
@Dependent
@Default
public class SsmcListProcedure implements SsmcDAO {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "DB")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<SsmcList> getSSMCList(String seriesInd, String styleInd, String materialInd, String colorInd)
{
    Query q = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("SsmcList");
    q.setParameter("p_series_ind", seriesInd);
    q.setParameter("p_style_ind", styleInd);
    q.setParameter("p_material_ind", materialInd);
    q.setParameter("p_color_ind", colorInd);
    return (List<SsmcList>) q.getResultList();

}
}
```

After redeploying, I receive the following errors in the logs when sending a POST request:

```
WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bug that already has a patch.
(JAX-RS + CDI).

check at support oracle.